# Adipoli plugin overly text

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i recently came across an exciting jquery plugin for image overlays http://jobyj.in/adipoli/
it says it has a text overlay function but i can't figure out how it works has anyone got a working example.

```
    <script>
  $('.hover').adipoli({
      'overlayText' : 'overlayText'
  });
```

just does the default overlay i need to put the gallery name as an overlay really like the effects of this plugin but open to suggestions of other plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: `jquery.adipoli.js`

Line: 64

```
//...
else if (settings.startEffect == "overlay") {
    element = $(this);
    element.hide();
    $(this).siblings('.adipoli-before').html(settings.overlayText).css({
//...
```

Thus in order to enable `settings.overlayText`, `settings.startEffect` must equal `overlay`.
Which will give you the example code for a working overlay demo of...

```
    $(function(){
        $('.hover').adipoli({
            'overlayText' : '<b>overLayText</b>',
            'startEffect' : 'overlay',
            'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
        });
    });
```

Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/tzE4V/2/

Full JSfiddle.net demo source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
                <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="http://jobyj.in/adipoli/css/adipoli.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <body>
      <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
      <img class="img-style row1" src="http://jobyj.in/adipoli/img/gallery-images/1_1.png"/>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://jobyj.in/adipoli/js/jquery.adipoli.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('.row1').adipoli({
          'overlayText' : '<b>overLayText</b>',
                'startEffect' : 'overlay',
                'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
            });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: you rock do you know if it is posable to get the overlay text from the image title?

Comment: `var overlayText = $('#imgID').attr('title')` ? Read this: http://api.jquery.com/attr/